# Using the sources from Ubuntu 14 into ubuntu 12

Tags: apt, upgrade

We made a very silly mistake in a server, using the sources in the sources.list file from ubuntu 14 into ubuntu 12.

The system still works but needless to say there are a lot of errors on upgrade.

Now the system seems to think it's a release 14, but it's not!

I was going to go and fetch the sources from 12 and try to start over so I could have a clean upgrade without having to reinstall but I just wanted to ask if it's the safe thing to do.

Any ideas?

I got the sources from here:

http://repogen.simplylinux.ch/generate.php

Answer (score 1):

if you ran upgrade command and no one package upgraded and you directly get error then no problem you can replace your  `/etc/apt/sources.list` entries with Ubuntu 12.04. generate from  [here](http://repogen.simplylinux.ch/generate.php) and copy and paste to your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file and then update

```
sudo apt-get update
```

or

if some packages upgraded then you can downgrade them but it is not sure you will get result equivalent to previous system. You can change this through pinning.

first do correct `/etc/apt/sources.list` with correct Ubuntu release .
then  create or edit  `/etc/apt/preferences`

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/preferences
```

add

```
Package: *
Pin: release v=12.04
Pin-Priority: 1001
```

save and run command

```
 sudo aptitude dist-upgrade
```

see [apt preferences document](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man5/apt_preferences.5.html)

```
 P > 1000
           causes a version to be installed even if this constitutes a
           downgrade of the package
```

priority is `1001` more than `1000` so it will downgrade packages that are installed in your system.

Comment: What if you upgraded some packages and it got cut off right in the middle? Cause we did upgrade a good number of packages, but obviously not all. The whole thing was a bit iffy even before we did that. For example, it kept exiting when I was trying to do do-release-upgrade and such.